# How to correctly show WCAT Fiddler results?

Tags: iis, internet-explorer, xml

Using the [WCAT Fiddler extension](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2010/05/11/using-the-wcat-fiddler-extension-for-web-server-performance-tests.aspx), I managed to get an XML result file being generated, but unfortunately I failed in having it displayed correctly with the XSL being applied.

According to the authors website, a result should look like:

[image]

While my result looks like this in Internet Explorer 10 (IE 10):

[image]

I've double checked to ensure that the generated XML file correctly references the "report.xsl" file. I've also tried calling the XML file from a HTTP URL instead of a File URL but with no different result.

I've also set up a VMware with Windows XP and IE 7, where the same files render correctly:

[image]

So it seems that this is an issue with IE10 and the "report.xsl" being shipped with the WCAT Fiddler extension.

**My Question:**

How to make the XSL of WCAT Fiddler work in IE 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this problem too. It appears that report.xsl is buggy in a way that older IE versions tolerate, but newer browsers don't. My Visual Studio reports:

- C:\Working\report.xsl (52,13): error: Variable 'i' has not been declared
- C:\Working\report.xsl (1182,36): error: The variable or parameter 'rowId' is either not defined or it is out of scope.
- C:\Working\report.xsl (1185,13): error: The variable or parameter 'state' is either not defined or it is out of scope.

One workaround I've used (admittedly awkward)

- Open the developer tools:

[image: F12 tools]

- Enable Compatibility mode

[image: Enable Compatbility mode]

I've used this in IE9; I assume it works in IE10 as well, but haven't tried it. And I too would like a better solution. Ideally someone proficient in xslt could fix report.xsl.

Answer (score 0):

open in studio, debug xslt, define the input file, you will get 3 errors in total
add var to the error with undeclared i:

```
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
```

and remove the $'s from state and the orther